# Safari Web Content quit unexpectedly

Tags: safari

This is a bit of a strange bug that I haven't seen before. When loading the login page for a webapp I'm working on in Safari (Mac OS 10.8.2), the entire browser crashes and quits, with the message "safari web content quit unexpectedly". I don't think I've ever seen a site actually crash a browser before, outside of an infinite loop in javascript or something (and really, it doesn't seem like it should be possible). Is there any Apache header or something that is known to crash Safari? Any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

**What I've Done:**

- Removed all meta tags and it still crashed.
- It is getting the SSL certificate before it crashes, because I got the security warning (certificate doesn't match the url, since I'm testing locally)
- It's crashing almost immediately, so I doubt that there's any javascript that's causing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone ever happens to stumble across this question, the problem ended up being using CSS3 transitions in conjunction with `calc()` values. Apparently having them together causes Safari to crash (before the transition is even triggered, I might add). I solved it by doing some simple browser detection to add a class to the body when the browser was anything but Safari, and only do the transitions related to `calc()` values on elements inside that class.

Answer (score 1):

Use the process of elimination. Remove some code, test app. If it doesn't work, continue removing code until you find the cause.